# Directory.GetFiles finds different number of files with each use

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've just hit a brick wall and I thought I could use some help. Basically, I have this code:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
        {
            try
            {
                    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                    {
                        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.JPG"))
                        {
                            // Start Creating Photo Objects and then adding them to the List
                            Image imageForPassing = new Bitmap(f);
                            Tuple<double, double> exifInfo = exifExtractor.ExtractCoordinates(imageForPassing);

                            if (exifInfo.Item1 != 0.0 && exifInfo.Item2 != 0.0)
                            {
                                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(f);

                                Photo photoObject = new Photo(fileName, exifInfo.Item1, exifInfo.Item2, f);
                                photosList.AddPhoto(photoObject);
                            }

                        }
                        DirSearch(d);
                    }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
```

Now, the problem with this code is that every single time I use this code sometimes it finds all the files. However, sometimes it doesnt find all the files, e.g. out of 48 existing files it only finds 25. On another run, it will find 46 files etc.

Any ideas, why this happens?

Comment: maybe sometimes you have permission sometimes not ? what exceptions did you get?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions at all. Thats the weird part.

Comment: I'd think that, based on the structure, an exception would mean everything would stop. Is that what's happening or is it omitting files within directories? Entire directories? is there any pattern to what's missing?

Comment: Not an answer, but this kind of situation really highlights the need for self-explanatory variable naming. `Directory.GetFiles(d, "*." + s,  ...` is pretty difficult to read!

Comment: What the exception would be though if sometimes it does find all the files and on another occasion it doesn't. When it doesnt find all files, the files that are missing are the ones after the last file that has been found and added to the list. Which also follows the same pattern they are listed inside the folder.

Comment: Is it weird that you're using SearchOption.AllDirectories, which searches sub directories, then then recursively calling your function on sub directories anyway?

Comment: First check if you are passing the same value for `sDir` parameter. Then check if any of those directories are being used by another program to `write/delete` files.

Comment: Huh. So, just to confirm, you're getting no output on the Console of the exception? I want to be sure you're not saying you have no *uncaught* exceptions.

Comment: Maybe this `exifExtractor.ExtractCoordinates(imageForPassing);` doesn't produce reliable results.

Comment: Thanks Jack0x539, fixed that. But I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: The value for sDir parameter shouldnt matter that much really since all the files are atm placed inside a single folder. So it must be failing on the GetFiles method, somewhere.

Comment: @rene, is it possible that it produces reliable result once and on another use it doesnt? I will post my exifExtractor class if necessary.

Comment: Add a Console.WriteLine("file:" + f); direct after the GetFiles foreach and this line Console.WriteLine("if file:" + f); inside the if, run it and check if you get consistent pairs

Comment: Okay, I just figured out what the problem might be. It told me it's "Out of Memory". Typical with recursive functions I guess (?) Does it matter that the JPG files are 4mb each and it deals with about 100 files?

Comment: Recursive calls usually run out of stack space before they run out of memory, depending on what you're doing.  unless your system only has 512 MB of RAM, 400 MB of memory (4MB per file x 100 files) shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The other thing is that `Directory.GetFiles` builds an array in memory of all of the matching files before it returns.  That can take a while to complete.  You'd be better off calling `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.  That uses less memory & your code starts processing files sooner.

Comment: Since I'm working with JPG's and I read 100 files , would Dispose method help my case to free the memory?